# Peeking azure storage message queue fails with python but works through the portal

Tags: python, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

I am trying to access a storage queue programatically with python but peeking at the messages fails with an Auth error:

```
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
RequestId:xxxx
Time:2020-12-10T08:03:46.1919000Z
ErrorCode:AuthorizationPermissionMismatch
Error:None
```

My code looks like this:

```
from azure.storage.queue import (
    QueueClient, TextBase64DecodePolicy
)
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential

credential = AzureCliCredential()
DEFAULT_SUBSCRIPTION_ID = "xxx"
DEFAULT_POISON_QUEUE_NAME = "webjobs-blobtrigger-poison"
storage_account_name = "stxxx"

url = f"https://{storage_account_name}.queue.core.windows.net/{DEFAULT_POISON_QUEUE_NAME}"
client = QueueClient.from_queue_url(url, credential, message_decode_policy=TextBase64DecodePolicy())

properties = queue_client.get_queue_properties() 
count = properties.approximate_message_count # works?!?

messages = queue_client.peek_messages(count) # exception
```

Note the storage account was created through terraform and has no special config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code you provide, you want to use Azure AD token to peek messages from Azure queue storage. If so, you need to assign some special Azure RABC role(**Storage Queue Data Contributor**, **Storage Queue Data Reader** and **Storage Queue Data Message Processor**) to the user or service principal you use to login in Azure CLI. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-azure-active-directory#permissions-for-queue-service-operations).

For example

1. Assign  `Storage Queue Data Reader` role to  the user or service principal

```
az role assignment create \
    --role "Storage Queue Data Reader" \
    --assignee <email> \
    --scope "/subscriptions/<subscription>/resourceGroups/<resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage-account>"
```

2. Sign out and log in again with Azure CLI

```
az logout
az login
az account set -s '<your subscription Id >'
```

3. code

```
from azure.storage.queue import QueueClient, TextBase64DecodePolicy
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential

credential = AzureCliCredential()

DEFAULT_POISON_QUEUE_NAME = "myqueue"
storage_account_name = "andyprivate"

url = f"https://{storage_account_name}.queue.core.windows.net/{DEFAULT_POISON_QUEUE_NAME}"
client = QueueClient.from_queue_url(
    url, credential, message_decode_policy=TextBase64DecodePolicy())

properties = client .get_queue_properties()
count = properties.approximate_message_count  
print(count)
messages = client.peek_messages(count)  
for message in messages:
    print("Message: " + message.content)
```

[image]